# How to remove duplicated posts from Tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

If you go to http://cargotheme.tumblr.com/ and click “Display as list”, you will see that all posts are duplicated. How should the theme be modified to fix this? (Theme source  located [here](https://github.com/jarred/cargo-theme/blob/master/theme.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too surprising, really: you have two `div .list` containing all your posts inside `div #main_column`: one ID-less and `#pages`. Remove one or the other and the issue goes away.